# Scala, why do I not need to import deduced types

Tags: scala, types, casting, jvm, return-type-deduction

I feel like I should preface this with the fact that I'm building my projects with sbt.

My problem is that, if at compile time a method returns something of an unimported type, in the file where I call the method, as long as I use type inference, everything compiles. Once I try to assign the unimported type to the var/val which I created with the return value of my function, I get a compiler error.

Lets say I have two classes in two package. Class `App` in package `main` and class `Imported` in package `libraries`. Lets further more say that we have a class `ImportedFactory` in the package main and that this class has a method for creating objects of the type Imported.

This code compiles just fine:

```
class App() {
    // method return object of type Imported
    val imp = ImportedFactory.createImportedObject() 
}
```

This doesn't:

```
class App() {
    // method return object of type Imported
    val imp : Imported = ImportedFactory.createImportedObject() 
}
```

This yet again does:

```
import libraries.Imported

class App() {
    // method return object of type Imported
    val imp : Imported = ImportedFactory.createImportedObject() 
}
```

This seems like rather strange behavior. Is this normal for languages with type inference at compile time and I've yet to notice it until now in go/C++ due to my ignorance ?

Does one of the two valid approaches (import&explicit type vs infered) have advantages/drawback over the other ? (expect for, of course, one being more explicit and verbose and the other one being shorter)

Is this black magic or does the Scala compiler accomplish these deductions in a rather straight forward way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*note: You'll get better search results with the term **type inference***

With `val imp = ImportedFactory.createImportedObject()` you are letting the compiler figure out what type `imp` should be based on *type inference*. Whatever type `createImportObject` returns, that's what type `imp` is.

With `val imp : Imported = ImportedFactory.createImportedObject()` you are explicitly stating that `imp` *is* an `Imported`. But the compiler doesn't know what you mean by that unless you... import... it.

Both approaches have merit:

**inferred types**

Inferred types are great for when you're throwing together code where the type should be obvious:

```
val i = 1 // obviously `i` is an int
val j = i + 10 // obviously still an int
```

It's also great for local vars/vals where the type would be too much of a pain to write

```
val myFoo: FancyAbstractThing[TypeParam, AnotherTypeParam[OhNoMoreTypeParams]] = ...
// vs
val myFoo = FancyThingFactory.makeANewOne()
```

The downside is that if you have allowed a public def/val to have an inferred type, it can be more difficult to determine how to use that method. For this reason, omitting type annotations is typically only used for simple constants, and in local vals/vars that "client code" doesn't have to look at.

**explicit types**

When you do want to write library-ish code (i.e. public vals/defs), the convention is to explicitly-type them.

Probably the simplest reason for this is because this:

```
def myLibraryMethod = {
  // super complicated implementation
}
```

is harder to understand than

```
def myLibraryMethod: String = {
  // super complicated implementation
}
```

Another benefit to explicitly-typing your code is when you want to expose a less-specific type than what the value actually is:

```
val invalidNumbers: Set[Int] = TreeSet(4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42)
```

In this example, you don't want client code to need to care that your `invalidNumbers` is actually a `TreeSet`. That's an implementation detail. In this case you're hiding some information that, while true, would be distracting.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing importing does is making a not fully qualified name available in the current scope. You could just as well write this:

```
class App() {
    val imp: libraries.Imported = ImportedFactory.createImportedObject() 
}
```

The reason you `import libraries.Imported` is for making the shorter name `Imported` available for you to write. If you let the compiler infer the type, you don't mention the type in your code, so you don't have to import its shorter name.

And by the way: this has nothing to do with dynamic casting in C++. The only mechanism at work in your code is type inference.

Comment: I misappropriated the term dynamic casting and that might have indeed caused quite a bit of confusion (and lack of suggestions) regarding my question, sorry.